# CSS media query being ignored

Tags: css, media-queries

This code is a part of my positionally-fixed website menu which controls the margin from the top to prevent overlap with the content.  It depends on how wide the screen is.  However, I can't understand why the `@media screen and (max-width: 329px) {}` condition is being ignored and overriden by the `@media screen and (max-width: 604px) {}` condition.  (FYI they represent breakpoints at which the fixed menu breaks onto a new line, requiring the content to be pushed down one line, correspondingly.)

Live demo: https://www.ashenglowgaming.com

```
@media screen and (max-width: 604px) {
  #menu-w-home-menu {
    line-height: 1.2em;
  }
  #main {
    margin-top: 89px !important;
  }
}

@media screen and (max-width: 329px) {
  #main {
    margin-top: 113px !important;
  }
  #menu-w-home-menu {
    line-height: 1.2em;
  }
}


/* For all larger screen sizes */

#main {
  margin-top: 66px;
}

#menu-w-home-menu {
  line-height: 1.2em;
}
```

Comment: Any screen that has a max-width of 329px also matches a max-width of 604px. And would also match a max-width of 10 miles.

Comment: Also you need to understand that **media queries do not change the specificity** of the rules they include.

Comment: Could you please explain your point about specificity?  Thanks.

Comment: Any rule with same-specificity selectors that comes after the selectors in the media query will overwrite these.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because of your css **order**. Place your normal css above the media query like below. It will work fine

```
#main {
  margin-top: 66px;
}

#menu-w-home-menu {
  line-height: 1.2em;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 604px) {
  #menu-w-home-menu {
    line-height: 1.2em;
  }
  #main {
    margin-top: 89px !important;
  }
}

@media screen and (max-width: 329px) {
  #main {
    margin-top: 113px !important;
  }
  #menu-w-home-menu {
    line-height: 1.2em;
  }
}
```

> *[More help on to understand the order](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity)*

I hope this will help you!

Answer (score 1):

Remember that the browser reads your css from top to button so you just have to re-order your css and media query